# How to make if-elif conditionals shorter for parsing

Tags: python, string, parsing, if-statement

I am trying to make a program that preforms certain tasks on certain user inputs, like incrementing or decrementing integers, adding charachter(s) to strings etc.
The user can give multiple commands in the same line.

As I am using `raw_input`, I can't (and don't want to) take multi-line inputs.

Is it possible to make the `if-elif-else` conditionals shorter, and yet keep them in a readable form?

```
for i in test_str:
    if i == '[':
        a += 1
    elif i == '(':
        b += 1
    elif i == ']' and c > 0:
        c -= 1
    elif i == ')'and d > 0:
        d -= 1
    elif c == 0 and d == 0:
        ret += i
    ... # more elifs
```

There are also possibilities for an `elif` like :

```
elif i == 'o':
    if test_str[test_str.index(i)+1] == i: # next char is same
         # handle
    else:
         # handle
```

I am using this for parsing.

Comment: It looks short enough to me. And it is still readable.

Comment: Well, it would help if you could expand the information you are sharing, as it stands, without knowing more, I don't see any real way to reduce this. A suggestion would be to map a dictionary to what should be done depending on the value of `i`.

Comment: What's the application? Are you writing a parser or brace matcher?

Comment: I'd say you could probably simplify your algorithm instead, but without more context that's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @eumiro Sorry, forgot to mention but there are more `elif` statements

Comment: @Schoolboy - if there are more of them, maybe you can group some of them in sub-branches. In the current example there is not much to do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is a string checker. I check for characters and do certain operations if necessary.

Comment: Perhaps you want to rethink your approach to your problem. Are you writing a parser?

Comment: I am Parsing the strings.

Comment: this is not very productive, nor is this question answerable - thus not a real question, unless you explain what *exactly* you are trying to accomplish...you can start by providing some input you have and by showing the output you would like to have.

Comment: @root I am trying to (it's hard to describe) make a program that preforms certain *tasks* on certain user inputs, such as incrementing/decrementing ints, adding chars to strings etc. The user can give multiple commands in the same line (as I am using `raw_input`, I can't and don't want to take multi-line inputs).

Comment: What are you parsing? Have you tried any of these http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reduce the amount of lines your code uses you can do simply `if - elif - else` statements on one line.

```
if i == '[':
    a += 1
elif i == '(':
    b += 1
elif i == ']' and c > 0:
    c -= 1
elif i == ')'and d > 0:
    d -= 1
elif c == 0 and d == 0:
    ret += i
```

Becomes:

```
if i == '[': a += 1   
elif i == '(': b += 1   
elif i == ']' and c > 0: c -= 1   
elif i == ')'and d > 0: d -= 1    
elif c == 0 and d == 0: ret += i
```

---

But instead of doing this, you should change the logic you are using.

First of all, you should be using a function, and I would suggest also some kind of mapping.

Example:

```
d = {
'[' : ('add', a, 1),
'(' : ('add', b, 1),
']' : ('method', my_method, ['sample_arg1', 'sample_arg2'], {'sample_kwarg' : 'sample value'})} 

def check_char(char, mapping):
    mapper = d.get(char, None)
    if mapper:
        if mapper[0] == 'add':
            mapper[1] += mapper[2]
        if mapper[0] == 'subtract':
            mapper[1] -= mapper[2]
        if mapper[0] == 'method':
            mapper[1](char, mapper[2], mapper[3])
    # you get the idea....

def my_method(char, *args, **kwargs):
    # deal with char....
```

Comment: I see it, I am not going to write your code for you, but you should use my example as a start to writing proper functions for your code. Further advise would be to wrap it all in a class and have a function for each type of combination/action you may have, map each situation to its most generic form, and then your interface will simply be to feed a stream, string, or char into your function and it will do the rest. :)

Comment: Could you tell me how to handle multiple elifs, using maps, not the code, but just a start, like an idea of what can be used.

Comment: You can map methods/functions to a dictionary, so you could have `d = {']' : my_method}` and then in your `check_char` you can send your input to a function by doing `mapper = d.get(char, None)` and if mapper is a function you simply call it: `mapper(char)` (which is like doing `my_method(char)` ) and then that function will deal with the input. - added to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the idea of mapper. And I knew about the single line if statements but they were not what I wanted. But I got what it seems I need. I don't see any updates though :)

Comment: Refresh the page? - I will add a bonus for you, methods with args. give me a minute.